# Why does my delta time displayed value larger than my time since request?

Tags: http, networking, dns, response, wireshark

Currently I am doing some research on how to determine the load page time/http response time using wireshark.

Lately I am noticed that the value for the time since request is bigger than value of Delta time displayed. As I understand, time since request is a used to measure the http performance and delta time displayed used to measure time between the packet. How am I going to measure the real http response time using wireshark?

One more things, sometimes when I load the page there is dns response(dns.time) and sometimes the packet just not shown. Is it possible if the network are using the proxy make the dns response not visible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Delta Time is the time between ***displayed*** packets while "time since request" (or `http.time`) is the time from the http request to the response, regardless of how many other packets are displayed in between the request and response.

Also the `http.time` value depends on whether you have TCP's *"Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams"* enabled or not.  If it's disabled, then `http.time` will measure the time between the request and the first segment of the response whereas if it's enabled, it will measure the time between the request and the last segment of the response, i.e., the segment that allows Wireshark to reassemble the entire response.  You should be sure to enable or disable that preference depending upon what exactly you're trying to measure.